# Provide the HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST for invalid UUID

Tags: java, spring

I have a controller method provided:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "get All Quotes By account id", content = {
                    @Content(mediaType = "application/json", array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = Quote.class)))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = MessageConstant.EMPTY_REQUEST_BODY_MSG, content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = MessageConstant.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND_MSG, content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = MessageConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_MSG, content = @Content)})

    @GetMapping("/accounts/{accountId}/quotes")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllQuotesByAccountId(@PathVariable UUID accountId) {
        try {
            if (isInvalidUUID(accountId)) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiResponseMessage.getGenericApiResponse(Boolean.FALSE, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                    MessageConstant.EMPTY_REQUEST_BODY_MSG), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            List<Quote> quotes = quoteService.getAllQuotesByAccount(accountId);
            if (quotes == null || quotes.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiResponseMessage.getGenericApiResponse(Boolean.FALSE, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                        MessageConstant.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND_MSG), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(quotes, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(MessageConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_MSG + ex.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiResponseMessage.getInternalServerError(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

This is the method I use for UUID check:

```
private boolean isInvalidUUID(UUID uuid) {
    return uuid == null || StringUtils.isBlank(uuid.toString());
}
```

Now, I would like to use annotation for the UUID validation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$", flags = {Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE})
public @interface UUIDValidated {
    
    String message() default "UUID format is invalid";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

So I imagine the method will be like this for using the annotation:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllQuotesByAccountId(@PathVariable @UUIDValidator UUID accountId){

   .....
}
```

How do I emulate the HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST when the UUID is not valid and whats the error we get when the UUID is invalid using this annotation?

Answer (score 1):

> whats the error we get when the UUID is invalid using this annotation

is something you can verify yourself (my money is on a `MethodArgumentNotValidException`) and you can emulate the `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` by simply adding an exception handler method to your controller:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class QuoteController {

    @GetMapping("/accounts/{accountId}/quotes")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllQuotesByAccountId(@PathVariable @UUIDValidator UUID accountId) {
    ...// your code
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    String handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
        return "Validation failed: " + e.getMessage(); //or: build custom error message using getAllErrors(), or: return an error object instead of a String, or: return ResponseEntity to further customize the response
    }
}
```

As a side note, if the way to handle validation errors should be consistent across all controllers within your app (and not just defined for this particular controller), consider moving the handler method to a `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: I am not completely sure what do you mean. Can you provide a complete code example for the mentioned controller?